# Как получить bean в @Bean?

Tags: java, spring, bean, spring-core

Есть следующий `@Bean`:

```
@Bean
public Book warAndPiece() {
    return new Book(3000, "War and Piece", "Tolstoy", );
}
```

Последний аргумент - объект `Brochure`. Как подключить его если он

- как `@Bean` в классе `Brochure`(думаю, что вызывать метод - не лучшая затея)
- как `bean` в файле конфигурации

Оба имеют свои `qualifier'ы`

Comment: делайте как параметр с qualifier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Bean
public Book warAndPiece(@Qualifier("brochure") Brochure brochure) {
    return new Book(3000, "War and Piece", "Tolstoy",brochure);
}
```

Comment: а кто заминусил то, и почему?

Comment: @JVic идея рабочая, но тот же сонар будет на это ругаться, объективно Qualifier не для этого создан, есть более лаконичные решения.

Comment: Но ведь идея то рабочая) да, согласен, не для того был создан. Но и ответ, считаю, не достойный минуса, разве что минуса с уточняющим комментом, а лучше просто с комментом, это же не откровенная дичь

Comment: @kaylil_01 "@Autowired is fundamentally about type-driven injection with optional semantic qualifiers.<...> they do not semantically express a reference to a unique bean id." - достаточно лишь указывать `qualifier'ы` не как конкретные элементы(источник(после 3 блока кода)): https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers).

Comment: @kaylil_01 Вообще же я не понимаю - как можно использовать `@Autowired` без `@Qualifier`. Ведь это по-сути заставляет либо делать нужный `bean` `n`-ого типа `primary`(А остальные получать по `qualifier'у`), либо делать его в единичном экземпляре(в смысле - один `bean` на класс). То есть - один шаблон на весь контейнер. Обычно в `Spring` приложениях так и происходит?

Comment: @Miron такая неоднозначность может встречается только при использовании одного интерфейса, других таких ситуаций обычно не возникает.

Comment: @kaylil_01 автор написал что у него 2 различных реализаций Бина, как ты это сделаешь без квалифайр? никак! ну только если стоит @ primary

Comment: @Санаев не две, просто `bean` brochure может быть как в конфигурации, так и как `@Bean` в коде. Я хотел увидеть, как можно получить его в обоих случаях. Оказалось, что `bean` получается одинаково.

Comment: Но проверить, как оно работает, не могу - [не находит `@Bean` warAndPiece](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1122718/no-bean-named-beanname-available-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-bean)

Comment: Но, вообще, да, у меня в действительности более одного `bean`. Это совершенно тривиальные, возможно, так вообще никто на практике не делает. Я только изучаю документацию spring(чуть более половины прочитал. Сейчас на [этом](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers) параграфе).

Comment: В дополнение - [вот описание](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java-injecting-imported-beans) этого действа(получение bean в @Bean)  из официальной документации

Answer (score 0):

Если бин Brochure используется только в этом bean-методе, то можете сделать так:

```
 @Bean 
 public Book warAndPiece(Brochure brochure(имя бина-метода, который создает этот бин) {
   return new Book(3000, "War and Piece", "Tolstoy", brochure); 
 }
```

И спринг сам внедрит эту зависимость, если же не только в этом одном bean-методе, то лучше заавтоварить в классе, где находится этот bean-метод и передать в метод.

Comment: если у Бина не будет @ primary - у тебя будет ошибка ! да и не думаю что внедрять по умолчанию Бин - правильное решение!

Comment: @Санаев я не заметил, что у него два бина, но тогда лучше инжектить по имени бина, а не через Qualifier, так как это Bean-метод.

Comment: тогда исправь свой ответ

Comment: @Санаев  что значит "внедрять бин по умолчанию"?

Comment: несколько бинов - @ autowired - @ primary

Comment: @Санаев это не мое мнение, что так правильно, это правила сонар линтера. Можете сами о них почитать.

Comment: хорошо. договорились