# No bean named 'beanName' available, не видит @Bean

Tags: java, spring, аннотации, bean, spring-core

Ошибка здесь:

```
Book warAndPiece = context.getBean("warAndPiece", Book.class);
```

Создание объекта `context` чуть ранее(все в `main(String[] args)`):

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("instantiation.xml");
```

`instantiation.xml` подключает аннотации:

```
<context:annotation-config/>
```

Сам `@Bean`:

```
@Bean
public Book warAndPiece(@Qualifier("warAndPieceBrochure")Brochure brochure) { // it is not recommended to set qualifier as id!
    return new Book(3000, "War and Piece", "Tolstoy", brochure);
}
```

Он в классе `Book`, который аннотирован как содержащий `@Bean'ы`:

```
@Configuration
public class Book {
    ...
}
```

Полный код ошибки:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:
>    No bean named 'warAndPiece' available

Все, что нужно, на первый взгляд, прописано. Что я упускаю?

---

Дополнение:
Попробовал сделать тестовый класс конфигурации с `@Bean` в том же пакете, что и класс `Main`:

```
@Configuration
public class TestBeanConf {
    @Bean
    public TestBeanConf testBean() {
        return new TestBeanConf();
    }
}
```

На строке

```
context.getBean("testBean");
```

Кидает аналогичную ошибку.

Comment: Попробуйте `ApplicationContext` заинжектить через конструктор или `@Autowired` и взять у него бин.

Comment: @dmtr Как? У меня же несколько xml файлов. Какой оно подставлять будет?

Comment: зачем вам вообще xml? Спринг сам конфигурирует бины

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смена

```
 <context:annotation-config/>
```

на

```
<context:component-scan base-package="ru.miron"/>
```

помогла. Все подключилось.

Comment: Костыль, но куда деваться. Также есть описание для первого: "only looks for annotations on beans in the same application context in which it is defined". Возможно, в этом кроется разгадка.

Answer (score 0):

Аннотацией @Configuration  помечается класс, в котором создаётся бин, а не в котором он описывается. Класс, содержащий метод

```
@Bean
public Book warAndPiece(@Qualifier("warAndPieceBrochure")Brochure brochure) { // it is not recommended to set qualifier as id!
    return new Book(3000, "War and Piece", "Tolstoy", brochure);
}
```

Помечен как @Configuration ?

Также, мне кажется, нужно @Autowired использовать с квалифаером.

Comment: "Он в классе `Book`", а этот класс помечен как `@Configuration`